# Joining two tables and getting duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables where each table has two columns in common (ID and Date). I want to get all the rows from Table 1 , state column from Table 2 and then also add another column for a flag showing if there was appointment or not. I was able to add the flag column without joining the two tables and using EXIST however when I join the 2 tables on ID to add state column I am getting extra rows in my output when I should be only getting 18 rows.

Table 1

```
ID, DateYM, Status
1,  2021-01-01, On
1,  2021-02-01, On
1,  2021-03-01, Off
1,  2021-04-01, On
1,  2021-05-01, On
1,  2021-06-01, On
2,  2021-01-01, Off
2,  2021-02-01, On
2,  2021-03-01, Off
2,  2021-04-01, On
2,  2021-05-01, On
2,  2021-06-01, On
3,  2021-01-01, On
3,  2021-02-01, Off
3,  2021-03-01, On
3,  2021-04-01, On
3,  2021-05-01, On
3,  2021-06-01, On
```

Table 2

```
ID, Appt_date, State, Appointment
1,  2021-01-12, set, Registered
1,  2021-04-14, notset, Registered
1,  2021-05-13, notset, Registered
2,  2021-02-12, set, Registered
2,  2021-04-17, set, Registered
2,  2021-05-15, notset, Registered
2,  2021-06-12, set, Registered
3,  2021-03-19, notset, Registered
3,  2021-06-10, notset, Registered
```

Expected result table:

```
ID, DateYM, Status, Appointment, State
1,  2021-01-01, On, Yes, set
1,  2021-02-01, On, No, null
1,  2021-03-01, Off, No, null
1,  2021-04-01, On, Yes, notset
1,  2021-05-01, On, Yes, notset
1,  2021-06-01, On, No, null
2,  2021-01-01, Off, NO, null
2,  2021-02-01, On, Yes, set
2,  2021-03-01, Off, No, null
2,  2021-04-01, On, Yes, set
2,  2021-05-01, On, Yes, notset
2,  2021-06-01, On, Yes, set
3,  2021-01-01, On, No, null
3,  2021-02-01, Off, No, null
3,  2021-03-01, On, Yes, notset
3,  2021-04-01, On, No, null
3,  2021-05-01, On, No, null
3,  2021-06-01, On, Yes, notset
```

Query that I used for mysql:

```
    select *, state,
    case when exists (
     select * from t2 
     where t1.id=t2.id 
     and date_format(t1.dateym, "%Y-%m") = date_format(t2.appt_date, "%Y-%m") and 
     t2.appointment='Registered') then 'Yes' else 'No' end Appointment 
    from t1
    join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

For a given ID, I am getting multiple rows for the same month when I join instead to having just 6 rows per ID. How do I get all the rows from table 1 and also 2 new columns from table 2?

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2af95411067b6d7f931ffaddb0e53ffc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEFT JOIN two tables with formatted date and ID

```
-- MySQL
SELECT t1.ID
     , t1.DateYM
     , t1.Status
     , (CASE WHEN t2.Appointment = 'Registered' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as Appointment
     , t2.state
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
       and DATE_FORMAT(t1.DateYM, "%Y-%m") = DATE_FORMAT(t2.Appt_date, "%Y-%m")
ORDER BY t1.ID, t1.DateYM
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef715b567a2d9a47f9796923386352a6